# Storing Select Query result in Variable Ruby on Rails

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, select

I wanted to know how we could store the result of my select query on a variable.

```
@ppt2 = Ppt.select('slide_name').where('id=?',4)
@ppt1 = Ppt.update_all({:time2=>@ppt2},['id like ?','1'])
```

Here, `slide_name` and `time2` are both text attributes of the same table `ppt`.

What happens on the above execution is that the `time2` field in `id=1` gets the value "`@ppt2`" whereas I want it to get the value of `slide_name` from `id=4` which does not get stored in `@ppt1`.

In other words, how do I store the value of the select query in `@ppt2` so that it can be used in the next line?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Call the `slide_name` method on your first result.

```
@ppt2 = Ppt.select('slide_name').find(4).slide_name
```